# Can I ask another question based on the previous question and its comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, questions

I don't know if it is duplication but I wanted to make another question which is modified based on my previous question and its comments.

For example, I posted a question about a claim and its proof. The comments suggested to modify part of the claim. So I plan to ask another question about the claim and the proof with a little modification.

Is there any other indications other than duplication if I ask another question like this?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. But generally if you continue on a previously answered question, reference that your new question is based on that. If the previous question hasn't received answers, feel free to edit it.

Comment: That's right. I need to cite the previous question. But if I just edit the previous question, it will not be found on the top of NEWEST question list thus it will be less probable to be entertained. That's why a new question gives a new start.

Comment: "if I just edit the previous question, it will not be found on the top of NEWEST question list" - that's true, but it *will* be moved to the top of the "Active" question list. I can't speak for other users, but I personally use the "Active" list almost exclusively, and therefore I *would* see your edited question.

Comment: @EddyPiedad if your previous question doesn't have any answers a new post is definetly **not** the way to go. Opt for editing, it will pop-up on the active page, which is way more useful anyways.

Comment: Great! I didn't know that this is how Active page works. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Somewhat related: *[Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/)*

Answer (score 1):

The usual criteria applies:

1. The questions have to be sufficiently different [to not be considered duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417477).
2. The new question as a stand-lone [must be focused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417486).
3. The new question must have sufficient [details and clarity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417485) and [be reproducible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417481).
4. Check the remaining specific site's guidelines, Stack Overflow has [a good overview of the close reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow).

Other than that there's been a recent post about [incremental answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379595) showing one interesting case of [204 different answers to the same question by one user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3Athis+user%3A70292) (not that I understand any of it, but it seems brilliant).